# iOS - Unable to reach 3rd instance of firebase project via FCM

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have 3 different Firebase projects that are initialized in a single application. The first app is initialized using the default `GoogleService-info.plist` file. 
The first two projects contain a Firebase iOS app with the same `bundle id` as the app. The third project contains an iOS app with an arbitrary `bundle id`.

I develop an SDK that uses Firebase to provide push notification service, and utility silent push functionality. The use case I describe here is one where the client app has its own Firebase project, the SDK has a client dedicated project, and another "Master" Firebase project that is used as the utility-cross-client Firebase project.

While FCM can reach the app via the first two projects (The ones with the same `bundle id`) it cannot reach the app via the third one (the cross-client one) due to `invalid-apns-credentials` error. Note that I generate the `fcmToken` correctly using  `Messaging.messaging().retrieveFCMToken(forSenderID::)` and that the same *APNs auth key* is used throughout all 3 projects.

I tried to solve it by adding a new `Firebase app` to the third project with the same `bundle id` as the application, and which allowed me be able to reach the application. However, I was still able to reach the client app even after I've delete the Firebase iOS app from the 3rd project (the one with the same `bundle id` not the "arbitrary one")

Comment: Hey elkorb. It would help if you could put the error logs. I'm not too familiar with iOS, but it's possible that the issue is the relationship between APNs and the bundle id. The part where you have to specifically provide the bundle id (in the [startup guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)) and the fact that FCM still communicates with APNs under the hood led me to this conclusion. With all that said, it would still make your post better if you add in more details. As of right now, this would probably be tagged as *off-topic: why isn't this code working?*

Comment: Thanks @AL., I edit my question.